# School Exercise - Python program

Tags: python

I'm not a programmer and not even a mathematician, just a curious father. My son got the homework with one task: there are 5 digits (for example: 1,3,5,8,0) and you need to find divisions with minimal remainder and maximum remainder using combination of these digits with following conditions: each digit is used only once, you should divide by tens (so by 10, 30, 50, 80) and dividend is constructed from 3 digits. So, for digits above it will be:

- 583 / 10 = 58 R 3 and 853 / 10 = 85 R 3 (smallest remainders solutions)
- 315 / 80 = 3 R 75 (biggest remainder solution)

So, using the google search I got this in Python and was thinking how would professionals approach this? Ideally I'd have not a list of sorted examples but just result: *like... ok, for this set of digits - division(s) with smallest remainders are/is: ... and with biggest are/is: ...*

So, if someone will find a minute and give some example, we'd be happy.

```
from itertools import permutations

l = ["1","3","5", "8"]

comb = permutations(l, 3)

t = ()

for i in comb:
    k = ""
    for j in i:
        k += j
    d = int(k)
    t = t + (d,) 

x = 0
r = 0
text = ""
dict = {}

for i in t:
    
    l2 = []
    for j in l:
        for k in str(i):
            l2.append(k)
        if j not in l2:
            j += "0"
            
            x = int(i) // int(j)
            r = int(i) % int(j)
            text = (str(i) + " / " + str(j) + " = " + str(x) + " R " + str(r))
            
            dict[text] = r

marklist = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])

for i in marklist:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Hey @Sergey, appreciate your afford as non coder. Could please you try to explain better your calculation or your desired output ?

Comment: isn't 318/80 the biggest remainder solution with a remainder of 78 or can numbers only appear once?

Comment: @Nin17 yes, the numbers can be used only once. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergey ok, see my answer, I've done both cases

Comment: @Rajan idea is to take 5 digits and following conditions find solution with greatest and smallest reminder of division. Divident should be 3 digits number, divisor should be tens, each digit is used once. So for five digits it's clear that it will be XXX / X0 = result, reminder. Where X is one of the digits except 0 since it's clear that 0 should be used for divisor. Let me know if I explained right (the thing is the task is in German, so I did my best)

Comment: so to be clear, you have 5 digit [a,b,c,d, 0] (0 is one of them) then you need to find the remainder out gof all the permuation of  these  4 digits (a,b,c,d) where these 4 digits make divident and divisior only ? so (a,b,c)/(d,0) combination where these a, b,c , d are interchangeable ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 yes, you put it right. And the divident is 3 digits number. abc / d0 = ... and all other combinations like that keeping in mind that each digit is used once, so aac / c0 - not acceptable. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a dictionary comprehension:

```
import itertools
lst = ["1","3","5", "8"]
#Convert the list of strings to integers
digits = [int(i) for i in lst]
#Create all possible 3 digit permutations
permutations = (sum(j*10**k for k, j in enumerate(i[::-1])) for i in list(itertools.permutations(digits, r=3)))
#Create a dictionary with the 'equation' as the keys and remainder as the value
result = {f'{i}/{10*j}':i%(10*j) for i in permutations for j in digits}
# Find the first occurrence of the maximum and minimum values
max_key = max(result, key=result.get)
min_key = min(result, key=result.get)
print([[k, v] for k, v in result.items() if v == result[max_key]])
print([[k, v] for k, v in result.items() if v == result[min_key]])
```

Output:

```
[['158/80', 78], ['318/80', 78]]
[['351/10', 1], ['351/50', 1], ['381/10', 1], ['531/10', 1], ['581/10', 1], ['831/10', 1], ['851/10', 1], ['851/50', 1]]
```

And if you only want the values to appear once in the 'equation', then change the dictionary comprehension to this:

```
result = {f'{i}/{10*j}':i%(10*j) for i in permutations for j in digits if str(j) not in str(i)}
max_key = max(result, key=result.get)
min_key = min(result, key=result.get)
print([[k, v] for k, v in result.items() if v == result[max_key]])
print([[k, v] for k, v in result.items() if v == result[min_key]])
```

Output:

```
[['315/80', 75]]
[['583/10', 3], ['853/10', 3]]
```

Comment: Wow... thank you. Also, is it possible that it outputs all possible solutions (if there are several of them with smallest or greatest reminder)? For example in this case there are two solutions for smallest:  583/10 3 and 853 / 10 = 85 3

Comment: @Sergey yes you can, I've edited it to do that

Comment: Thank you a lot. I need to process this )

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension, plus some join and format methods to make it cleaner, here is how (you can of course change the texts if you dont like them or wish to have a more detailed ones):

```
from itertools import permutations


def smallest_biggest_div(input_l, dividors):
    """Gives the corresponding permutations to the biggest and smallest 
    reminders for a certain list of values and dividors"""

    # create different combinations
    combinations = [int(''.join(map(str, per))) for per in permutations(l, 3)]

    # calculate the smallest and biggest reminders.
    reminders = [(comb, comb % div, div) for div in dividors for comb in combinations
                 if not list(set.intersection(set(str(comb)), set(str(div))))]
    smallest_r = min([reminder[1] for reminder in reminders])
    biggest_r = max([reminder[1] for reminder in reminders])

    # get the smallest and biggest reminder's corresponding permutations and display them
    print(
        f'The permutations related to the biggest reminder {biggest_r} are : \n',
        ' '.join(['perumtation: {0}, with dividor: {2}\n'.format(*result) for result in reminders if result[1] == biggest_r]), 
        end='\n')
    
    print(
    f'The permutations related to the smallest reminder {smallest_r} are : \n',
    ' '.join(['perumtation: {0}, with dividor: {2}\n'.format(*result) for result in reminders if result[1] == smallest_r]), 
    end='\n')

# test
l = [1, 3, 5, 8]
d = [10, 20, 30, 50, 80]
smallest_biggest_div(l, d)
```

output:

```
The permutations related to the biggest reminder 75 are : 
 perumtation: 315, with dividor: 80

The permutations related to the smallest reminder 3 are :
 perumtation: 583, with dividor: 10
 perumtation: 853, with dividor: 10
```

Comment: the biggest remainder is 75 and the smallest is 3?

Comment: I used different values for the test, you can use yours and you'll surely get the same results

Comment: you don't, that's my point with ```l = [1, 3, 5, 8]``` and ```d = [10, 30, 50, 80]``` you get the biggest remainder is 53 and the smallest if 5

Comment: here, fixed the problem, though the biggest reminder is 78 not 75 , 318 % 80 = 78

Comment: @mrCopiCat see the comments you can't have numbers occurring more than once in the 'equation' therefore the biggest is 75 and smallest is 3 as opposed to 78 and 1

Comment: @Nin17 sorry you were right I didnt pay attention to that, it now outputs the right result.

Answer (score 0):

not so efficient solution, but it handle all OP condition,

idea is make permutation of size 3 of all 4 digit in array except 0. and then for each permutated value ie 135 find the divisor for it . which is left out 4th digit ie 8, so divisor will be 80 . so we got one divisor and divident as 80, 135 .

once these values are found then get the remainder. save result it an list. and return the max and min remainder value from that list.

```
from itertools import permutations as p
def func(arr):
    fil_arr = [i for i in arr if i!=0]
    sum_a = sum(arr)
    res = [[i, (sum_a-sum(i)) *10 ] for i in p(fil_arr, 3)]
    print(res)
    result = []
    for a, b in res:
        a = sum(a[len(a)-i-1]* 10**i for i in reversed(range(len(a)-1,-1,-1)))
        result.append([a, b])
    solution = []
    for a, b in result:
        solution.append(a%b)
    return max(solution), min(solution)
```